# Frozen columns only update the first row smoothly when scrolling

Tags: php, tabulator

With a frozen first and last column in Tabulator, when scrolling, only the first row of data will move the frozen columns while scrolling- all remaining rows update all at once, after scrolling has stopped, in one big jump.

Looking at the frozen_columns.js module, the layoutColumnPosition function takes an allCells parameter.  In the scrollHorizontal function, allCells is false.  Forcing this to true causes the frozen columns to update exactly as expected.

Why should I have to do this?  Do I have my frozen columns configured incorrectly?  Here are the options for the first (left-most) one:

```js
{
    cssClass: 'massActionColumn',
    align: 'center',
    headerSort: false,
    resizable: false,
    frozen: true,
    titleFormatter: function(cell, formatterParams) {
        return '<input title="Select All" type="checkbox" id="selectAllBox2" class="form">'
    },
    formatter: function(cell, formatterParams) {
        var auditId = cell.getRow().getData()[0];
        return '<input name="mass_action_ids[]" value="' + auditId + '" type="checkbox" class="mass_action_checkbox" />'
    }
}
```

Again, fairly confused as to why the allCells parameter is not set to true in frozen_columns.js, as scrolling then behaves like it does in Tabulator's examples.